# Including jQuery in Wordpress-Plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm using jQuery/ajax in my Wordpress-Plugin. When I link jQuery this way, it even works

```
add_action('wp_head', 'hook_files');


function hook_files()
{
    $output = "
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css'> ";

    echo $output;    
}
```

But I know that this is not the right way to do. So [I looked up the documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Link_the_script.aculo.us_Library) and implemented this:

```
function enqueue_my_scripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-core' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_scripts');
```

But then it doesn't work anymore... Is there something wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the enqueue to load the script, especially jquery, so you could just fire it like so: [Recommended Solution]

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

Or a more elobrate approach:

```
function my_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
wp_register_style( 'prefix-style', plugins_url('mystyle.css', __FILE__) );
wp_enqueue_style( 'prefix-style' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','my_scripts');
```

Unless you want to use a cdn or a google repo for jquery, then i would recommend doing the following:

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js', array('jquery'));
```